# How to restrict any special character(%,#, or any letters) in the URL of angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript

Being new to Angular world, I would appreciate help in restricting by throwing an error message when user tries to add/type any special character or any extra letter at the end of the URL.

I have got stuck in the following scenario's:

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ql4E.png)
   this is when i tend to add # and soo... after the **/home**  in the given http://localhost:51467/home URL and after entering the output is  **it remains in the same screen**.
2. When add %jbkjb after after the **/home**  in the given http://localhost:51467/home URL and after entering the output is **it redirects to the home page and at time it throws error as.**
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgQAS.png)
3. When add any /homeadsafsf any gribrish value after **/home**  in the given http://localhost:51467/home URL and after entering the output is **it throws and error as follows.**
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm9Tu.png)

I m trying to throw an error message in the UI itself using alert if any of the above scenario's are encountered. but not able achieve yet.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place ?

Comment: to restrict user to add in any special character in the URL.

Comment: And again, why would you want to do that ?

Comment: to prevent URL tampering.

Comment: And again, why ??

Comment: Can you be specific, what exactly are you asking about? I have already mentioned to prevent URL tampering.

Comment: Because no-one does that. You don't control URL input.

Comment: I understand that no one can control the query param but what if anyone adds  gebbrish value in the URL, then how that can be handled by route

Comment: There are fallback routes in Angular, simple as that.